# What does shap.utils.sample do when used inside a KernelExplainer or TreeExplainer instance in Python's SHAP library?

Tags: python, machine-learning, shap

Can someone explain what shap.utils.sample does when used inside an explainer instance (eg. KernelExplainer or TreeExplainer). For example, what is the difference when I use

```py
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, shap.utils.sample(X_test, 75))
shap_values = explainer(X_test)
```

vs.

```py
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, X_test)
shap_values = explainer(shap.utils.sample(X_test, 75))
```

vs.

```py
explainer = shap.TreeExplainer(model, shap.utils.sample(X_test, 75))
shap_values = explainer(shap.utils.sample(X_test, 75))
```

For a bit of context, I am trying to reduce the runtime of my script that uses SHAP without necessarily reducing its accuracy too much. I am also working with a multi-class classification problem. Thank you!

I tried to look for answers in the documentation and some forums but I can't get any substantial explanation regarding this.